# Can't access routes other than /

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, digital-ocean

I've created a basic droplet on digitalocean and I got myself a domain name. When I want to get /, I get a good 'Hello World' response, but when I want to access any other route, for example '/x', I get a `Cannot {{request}} /x` error. I believe it's a problem with my nginx config. I've also set up HTTPS with LetsEncrypt. Nginx config and Express code below.

Nginx config:

```
# HTTP - redirect all requests to HTTPS:
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# HTTPS - proxy requests on to local Node.js app:
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name your_domain_name;

    ssl on;
    # Use certificate and key provided by Let's Encrypt:
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/your_domain_name/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/your_domain_name/privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

    # Pass requests for / to localhost:8080:
    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
            proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Here's the index.js file

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.get('/x', function(req, res) {
  res.send('x')
})

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('hello world')
})

app.listen(8080, function() {console.log('App started')})
```

Any ideas? I want to be able to route requests without touching the nginx config every time I add a new route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the trailing slash from the `proxy_pass` setting:

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
```

From the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass):

> If `proxy_pass` is specified without a URI, the request URI is passed to the server in the same form as sent by a client when the original request is processed, or the full normalized request URI is passed when processing the changed URI.

Comment: Thanks a lot - that's what I missed! It works now. Have a wonderful day, man, thank you once again.